# Getting access token in facebook to access work_history

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api

I want to integrate fb into my website and pull work_history. I've literally gone through every forum question and read the fb pages. From what I've read you need a token to access the info. Do you also need to run a fql query? How can I get the token to get friends work_history? Below is what I tried.

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$token  = array($facebook->getAccessToken());

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

    $fql = "SELECT uid, name, work_history, FROM user WHERE 
    uid = ' . $user.'";
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api(array(
                                   'method' => 'fql.query',
                                   'query' => $fql,
                                 ));


    echo '<pre>Pic: ' . $ret_obj[3]['work_history'] .'</pre>';                           


 } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user_profile = null;
  }
}

if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
  'scope' => 'user_work_history',
  'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.myweb.com')

  );
}
```

Comment: */ is just a typo. No errors at all, just nothing

Comment: _“Below is what I tried.”_ – posting example code is fine – but you forgot to describe what your actual _problem_ with it is (and don’t go and say “does not work!” now).

Comment: @CBroe I can't get the work_history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "user" table doc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/ says that work_history is deprecated and you should use the column work instead. Also, you need the user_work_history permission to access the data.
FWIW, I ran this query - SELECT uid, name, work FROM user where uid = me() and it works for me.